# Block cart icon for certain customer tags on Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to block customers tagged with "Wholesale" from the cart icon but it seems to block everybody. I've also tried to add this tag markup but won't let me add in {% include %} without giving me some type of error.

```
          {% unless customer.tag contains 'Wholesale' %}
            {% include 
            <li class="site-nav__item">
              <a href="/cart" class="site-nav__link site-nav__link--icon cart-link js-drawer-open-right" aria-controls="CartDrawer">
                <span class="icon-fallback-text">
                  <span class="icon icon-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="fallback-text">{{ 'layout.cart.title' | t }}</span>
                </span> 
                <span class="cart-link__bubble{% if cart.item_count > 0 %} cart-link__bubble--visible{% endif %}"></span>
              </a>
            </li> %}
           {% endunless %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `include` usage is wrong. It is used to load only snippet files. Just remove `{% include` and it's corresponding `%}` and you're good to go.

Also it's `customer.tags`.

```
 {% unless customer.tags contains 'Wholesale' %}
  <li class="site-nav__item">
    <a href="/cart" class="site-nav__link site-nav__link--icon cart-link js-drawer-open-right" aria-controls="CartDrawer">
      <span class="icon-fallback-text">
        <span class="icon icon-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="fallback-text">{{ 'layout.cart.title' | t }}</span>
      </span> 
      <span class="cart-link__bubble {% if cart.item_count > 0 %} cart-link__bubble--visible{% endif %}"></span>
    </a>
  </li> 
 {% endunless %}
```

Comment: Thanks HymnZ but when I do this it blocks from both tagged and non tagged customers.

Comment: Its `customer.tags` not `customer.tag`

Comment: Still the same thing happens.

Comment: Can you show me the output of this? `<script>console.log('Customer Tags:{{ customer.tags }}')</script>` . Place that line of code below your code above. The check the debug console of your browser for the output. Also note that `customer.tags` works only if a customer is signed in.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this. I've added the script below the code as you've suggested. I typed in debug into the console and there is not ouput.

Comment: Thanks HymnZ I got it figured out. The "Wholesale" is case sensitive. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

This should probably be a comment - but I need to include a code example...

As HymnZ has mentioned - customer.tags will only work if the customer is signed in.

If the customer is not signed in, they will be treated as a 'regular' customer.

If you want to hide the cart button until any type of customer is logged in - you'd need to wrap everything in an `{% if customer %}`

Then, if you wish to check if the customer is wholesale, you'd use

`{% unless customer.tags contains 'Wholesale' %}`

So to put it all together:

```
{% if customer %}
{% comment %} Customer is logged in. {% endcomment %}
{% unless customer.tags contains 'Wholesale' %}
  <li class="site-nav__item">
    <a href="/cart" class="site-nav__link site-nav__link--icon cart-link js-drawer-open-right" aria-controls="CartDrawer">
      <span class="icon-fallback-text">
        <span class="icon icon-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="fallback-text">{{ 'layout.cart.title' | t }}</span>
      </span> 
      <span class="cart-link__bubble {% if cart.item_count > 0 %} cart-link__bubble--visible{% endif %}"></span>
    </a>
  </li> 
 {% endunless %}
{% endif %}
```

*** Edit ***

Following on from Gino's comment: 
It seems there are some inconsistencies with how Shopify handles tags. My first thought was case sensitivity, however, I couldn't quite remember if tags were case sensitive.

So I logged into my store - and tried to add 'Test' and 'test'.

Once I had added 'Test' - it appeared as 'Test', but I couldn't add 'test' - as Shopify regarded 'Test' and 'test' as the same (case insensitive).

However, in the ui - it showed 'Test' (case sensitive) - which threw me into thinking it is case sensitive (it was nearly 3am when I answered)

A quick google, I found this post from Tobi Lutke - the chap who wrote Shopify https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-discussion/t/tag-use-6631 - please see the last comment: "Tags are always downcased automatically." ......

So of course - if the tag is downcased automatically, and you're checking against the string 'Wholesale' it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in Rob, this makes a lot of sense. I figured out my problem and that is "Wholesale" is case sensitive.